# Add bounty ended information in the post timeline

Tags: feature-request, bounties, revisions-list, timeline

Currently there are two places that show information regarding bounties on a post.

- The revision list (/posts/[postid]/revisions)
- The post timeline (/posts/[postid]/timeline)

Currently both show information about badges differently.
The timeline shows:

[image]

The revision history shows:
[image]

Notice the information that is present in the revision history, but is absent in the timeline?

Now you might argue, there is no room for such info in the timeline, but I beg to differ, as the headers for the timeline table clearly indicate there is room for "comment[s]" :
[image]

**Can we include the information shown on the timeline in the revision history as well?** In this case specifically the "with bmike's answer chosen by rene" part. In this way we have all the available information present in the posts timeline, and don't need to go elsewhere to look for information.

Comment: There plenty of questions that have multiple bounties awarded. It would be useful to know when a bounty was awarded to a particular answer and by whom without having to get on the computer and use the tool tips or open every answer's history.